# Does there exist a prime that is only consecutive digits starting from 1?

Tags: prime-numbers

This is a problem I came up with the other day, and have absolutely no clue how to solve. The problem is: does there exist a number in the set $K$ that is prime, where $K$ is defined to be the set of all numbers that follow this pattern:
$$1$$
$$123$$
$$12345$$
$$123456789$$
$$12345678901$$
$$1234567890123$$
$$ ... $$

I have left out numbers that end in even digits such as $1234$ because they are obviously not prime, although they are still members of the set.

In WolframAlpha I have checked up to $1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789$ but still found $0$ primes.

My intuition is telling me to believe that there is no such prime, but I am reluctant to believe that given that I have no formal proof.

For those of you who want specifics, the set $K$ is defined such that:

$$K_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{10^{n-i}D(n)}$$
given that $D(x)$ is the last decimal digit of $x$, or equivalently the remainder of $x/10$, and if you are still craving a mathematical formula, take this: $D(x)=x-10\lfloor{\frac{x}{10}}\rfloor$

UPDATE:
SOLVED (by exhaustion):

Shortest one I could find:

> 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901

Comment: If there is one, it can only end in $1$ or $7$.

Comment: Can you please explain how you got to that conclusion?

Comment: It can't end in $5$ or in an even digit. Nor in $3$ or $9$, since then the sum of its digits, and thus the entire number, would be a multiple of $3$.

Comment: Sorry I'm not exactly a whiz at this, why couldn't it end in a 5?

Comment: Because it would be a multiple of $5$.

Comment: Haha wow way to make me feel stupid

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit:** code fixed, uses gmpy2 now.

The power of brute force: I wrote a quick python program, and

> 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901

is a prime based on gmpy2's probable prime Miller-Rabin test.

Code if you want to verify:

```
import gmpy2

digit = 1
number = 1234567890
while True:
    number = 10*number + digit
    if gmpy2.is_prime(number):
        print(number)
        break

    digit = (digit + 1)%10
```

Comment: Mathematica's PrimeQ verifies this is indeed a prime.

Comment: According to WolframAlpha, that is not a prime number

Comment: http://cl.ly/image/2p240S0L110o

Comment: ASKASK - that isn't the same number qwr put in his answer.

Comment: @ASKASK your input obviously got cut off, it ends in 0.

Comment: If you want proof that PrimeQ does tell you its prime, http://imgur.com/oSyTlL9

Comment: Well done, you have earned yourself a victory

Comment: I built my own program in java and I believe I found one shorter than yours

Comment: @ASKASK interesting, maybe the Miller-Rabin test missed a prime, but it is extremely fast

Comment: @Batman: Of course Mathematica's `PrimeQ` doesn't prove primality, it does a probable-prime test. you need `ProvablePrimeQ` to prove primality.

Comment: Oops, yeah. Still, ProvablePrimeQ returned true. =)

Comment: @qwr It's impossible for the actual Miller-Rabin test to miss a prime, since it only proves compositeness.  There must be an implementation error.

Answer (score 1):

If PARI/gp is to be believed then K_n is prime for n=171,277,367,561 and 567.

Comment: what is PARI/gp and how did you get those numbers?

Comment: PARI/GP is a computer algebra system with the main aim of facilitating number theory computations.  It is free.  The built-in function isprime(x) uses a combination of algorithms to prove x is prime (or not).

Comment: My GP script for this problem (probably similar to yours): `N=0;for(n=1,1e4,if(ispseudoprime(N=10*N+n%10),print1(n", ")))`

Comment: Yes, I used a similar script.  Each of the five numbers above is provably prime.  If I were a betting man (which I am), I would wager these are the only n for which K_n is prime.

Comment: According to http://oeis.org/A120819, there is at least one more such prime.