# Questions about primes made from consecutive numbers starting from 1

Tags: prime-numbers

Similar to: [Does there exist a prime that is only consecutive digits starting from 1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788630/does-there-exist-a-prime-that-is-only-consecutive-digits-starting-from-1)

Let $b_n=\overline{a_1a_2a_3\dots a_n}$ and $a_n=n$. For example $b_{11}=  1234567891011$. I have a couple of questions about the primes in the sequence $b_n$.

1. What is the lowest number $n$ such that $b_n$ is prime (if there is is an $n$)?
2. Are there infintely many primes in the sequence $b_n$?
3. Do these primes have a name?

The first question was an excercise in Clifford Pickover's *A Passion For Mathematics*. I don't know if there is a way to find the answer to the first question without using a computer.

Like in [Does there exist a prime that is only consecutive digits starting from 1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788630/does-there-exist-a-prime-that-is-only-consecutive-digits-starting-from-1), $n$ cannot be an even number (or else $b_n$ would be even). Thanks.

Comment: If noone finds an answer, the recursion is
$$b_{n+1} = 10^{\lfloor \log_{10}(n+1) \rfloor} b_n + n + 1$$
So you can write a script to test, similar to the linked question.

Comment: @AlexR Thanks, I still hope someone finds an answer though.

Comment: You should add an example just to make sure people understand the notation. For example, I believe that $b_{11}$ is the thirteen-digit number 1,234,567,891,011; confirming that would be helpful.

Comment: None of $b_2,\dots,b_{2000}$ is prime. But a probabilistic heuristic suggests that infinitely many of the $b_n$ should be prime, although they will be extremely rare.